# How to use dynamic variable in array with diff name

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Here I have code such as following.

```
$Var =  "Gas";
$Gasname[0] ="abc";
$Gasno[1] = 123;

echo ${$Var."name"[0]};
```

I have condition on $Var if value is Gas I will user Gase array in else case have to use another array like wise there are dynamic types of array.

Is there a way I can use dynamic array variable name.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Use array with keys: `array('gas' => [], 'another_gas' => []')`

Answer (score 1):

You were nearly there, the array index is not part of the variable name.

```
echo ${$Var."name"}[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `[0]` out of `${}` part, as it's not part of dynamic name:

```php
$Var =  "Gas";
$Gasname[0] ="abc";
$Gasno[1] = 123;

echo ${$Var."name"}[0];
```